# Set up sign-in for multi-tenant Azure Active Directory - Single Button for all tenants

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want to allow multiple Azure AD customers to sign-in into my app using their own AAD accounts.

For that I was considering this tutorial [Set up sign-in for multi-tenant Azure Active Directory using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy), but in the section "***Configure Azure AD as an identity provider***" **point 5** says "*Under the TechnicalProfile element, update the value for DisplayName, for example, Contoso Employee. This value is displayed on the sign-in button on your sign-in page.*"

By reading that section it seems to me that I will end up with an array of buttons, one for each AAD customer.

Is it possible to have a single button, like "Work account" to encapsulate all possible AAD tenants? and then internally figure out which ones is the right one?(maybe based on email domain..)

Answer (score 2):

It will be a single button with a single name and allow any azure ad account to login.

Comment: Awesome! I will try it out then. Thanks!

Comment: Reading the XML document inside section _Configure Azure AD as an identity provider_ it's obvious that for one DomainName element we have multiple ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes elements... though the suggestion of naming the button Contoso is kind of misleading... maybe better to name it **Work Account**